# npapi plugin_invoke function return string value garbage characters

Tags: plugins, safari, npapi, firebreath

npapi code:

```
bool plugin_invoke(NPObject *obj, NPIdentifier methodName, const NPVariant *args, uint32_t argCount, NPVariant *result) {
NPUTF8 *name = browser->utf8fromidentifier(methodName);
if(strcmp(name, plugin_method_name_getAddress) == 0){
    NPString password;
    if(argCount > 0) {
        password = NPVARIANT_TO_STRING(args[0]);
    }
    const char * StringVariable = password.UTF8Characters;
    char* npOutString = (char *)malloc(strlen(StringVariable+1));
    if (!npOutString)
        return false;
    strcpy(npOutString, StringVariable);
    STRINGZ_TO_NPVARIANT(npOutString, *result);
    browser->memfree(name);
    return true;
}
return false;
```

}

html code:

```
function run() {
    var plugin = document.getElementById("pluginId");
    var passwordBeforEncryption =  document.getElementById("passwordFeild");
    if(plugin){
        var value = plugin.getAddress("hello, just test it");
            alert(value);
    }else{
        alert("plugin is null");
    }
```

}

The right result should be: "hello, just test it", but sometimes return"hello, just test itÿÿÿÿ". It only sometimes not all time!

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [chrome newer version(14) does not give a null terminated string as part of NPVariant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807917/chrome-newer-version14-does-not-give-a-null-terminated-string-as-part-of-npvar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not in your html,you shuld see **NPString** structure.

```
typedef struct _NPString {
    const NPUTF8 *UTF8Characters;
    uint32_t UTF8Length;
} NPString;
```

The member **UTF8Length** indicate the length of your string,so you should do as below:

```
const char * StringVariable = password.UTF8Characters;
char* npOutString  = (char*)browser->memalloc(password.UTF8Length+1);
if (!npOutString) {
    return false;
}
memcpy(npOutString  , password.UTF8Characters, password.UTF8Length);
npOutString[password.UTF8Length] = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks you tell me the real problem and give me the demo code!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are allocating the memory incorrectly:

```
char* npOutString = (char *)malloc(strlen(StringVariable+1));
```

should be:

```
char* npOutString = (char *)malloc(strlen(StringVariable)+1);
```

to correct the length.

However, in order for the browser to be able to free the memory, you should be using:

```
char* npOutString = (char *)NPN_MemAlloc(strlen(StringVariable)+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, fond the answer!
In html code:

```
var value = plugin.getAddress("hello, just test it");
```

should be like this:

```
var value = plugin.getAddress("hello, just test it\0");
```

at string end need "\0"

Comment: This works, but the real problem is that your plugin code is wrong. You should be using the string length (see the duplicate question), not assuming that it's a null-terminated string.

Comment: Thanks you tell me the real problem!